# Play Execution exception: NoClassDefFoundError occured : javax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status

Tags: java, web-services, maven, playframework

Good day all.
I met with the next problem.
In project we are use play framework module for UI part And rest-service module for logic part and model part with enums.
And i met with the next problem. 
When i use the Enum from other module (code below):

```
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public enum ErrorCodeEnum {
 BAD_DATE_FORMAT("E2021", "Can not parse date", Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);

    ErrorCodeEnum(String code, String message, Response.Status status) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
        this.status = status;
    }
...
}
```

And try to use it in play ui part, in controller:

```
import module.FormParser;
import  module.breadcrumb.Breadcrumb;
import  module.entities.Holiday;
import  module.entities.HolidayApprover;
import  module.entities.Profile;
import  module.entity.AuthenticationObject;
import  module.enums.*;
import  module.exception.WSException;
import  module.security.RoleCheck;
import service.WSWrapper;
import service.WSWrapper.ProfileService;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import controllers.auth.Authentication;
import controllers.security.SecurityHelper;
import jobs.workorders.startup.FileSystemJob;
import models.PersonToIdNameAdapter;
import models.enums.DashboardView;
import models.form.*;
import models.persistence.Person;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.Validate;
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Days;
import persistence.PersonRepository;
import play.Logger;
import play.Play;
import play.data.validation.Valid;
import play.data.validation.Validation;
import play.i18n.Messages;
import play.mvc.After;
import play.mvc.Before;
import play.mvc.Http;
import play.mvc.With;
import utils.ProfilesLoader;
import utils.Utils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

@With(Authentication.class)
public class Employees extends Application {
...
@Breadcrumb(level = 3, key = "breadcrumb.holiday.request", parentKey = "breadcrumb.raise.request")
    public static void holidayRequest(@Valid HolidayForm holidayForm, List<String> approvers, String forPerson) {
...
//Here i have a problem with compilation
ErrorCodeEnum err = ErrorCodeEnum.ACC_PERMISSION_DENIED; 
...
}
```

In maven external libraries one of the module  i already have in dependencies javax.ws.rs.ap:2.0.1 library.
And i met with the play framework during runtime compilation the next problem:

Execution exception in brouser from play:

```
NoClassDefFoundError occured : javax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status
In /app/controllers/Employees.java (around line 449)

ErrorCodeEnum err = ErrorCodeEnum.ACC_PERMISSION_DENIED;
```

in console output:

```
Execution exception (In /app/controllers/Employees.java around line 449)
NoClassDefFoundError occured : javax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: javax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:229)
        at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status
        at module.enums.ErrorCodeEnum.<init>(ErrorCodeEnum.java:69)
        at module.enums.ErrorCodeEnum.<clinit>(ErrorCodeEnum.java:7)
        at controllers.Employees.holidayRequest(Employees.java:449)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:527)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:478)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:454)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:449)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 9 more
```

Enums from the same modules used without any compilation problems. I this the rison is conflict with javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Which IDE are you using buddy for development and creation of jar/war?

Comment: use Intellig IDE, build creation of jar/var - maven.

Comment: Are you running the application using Intellij?

Comment: No, through console.

Comment: what command are you using mate?

Comment: how it's relate? project have ierarhy of maven modules. first of all mvn clean install for root maven modules, that have in modules other parts of application. later with tomcat start rest services and separately start play framework (play run).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by myself. Play need separately add dependency for play compilation. Add to the play dependencies.yml:

```
- javax.ws.rs -> javax.ws.rs-api 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use diffrent version from current dependencies. and you can also try these dependencies, add dependencies into pom.xml and update the project.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: project have 4 separately maven modules, that's unite in one maven-parent module. Model maven module already have javax.ws.rs-api 2.0 dependency (where located ErrorCodeEnum  that i need to use).  And if i separately add maven dependency in UI model wih javax.ws.rs-api 2.1. Result - the same exception.